# Nexus 7 (2013) fastboot connection to PC

Tags: fastboot, linux, nexus-7, windows, usb-connection-mode

I've been trying for a few days to install LineageOS on a Google Nexus 7 (2013 version, or "flo"), using this guide [here](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/flox/install), but the USB cable connection seems to be very unstable for anything to work properly. It seems like there's a problem in the cable or the USB port, but it is still charging normally (even if the data connection seems frail) and I thought maybe someone has more information.

On Windows, the USB connection to the tablet has always been unstable, with it popping in and out of the devices listed on "device manager". I think I have the proper drivers, since I managed to follow the LineageOS installation up to the repartition step. After I entered the "modify" command on adb shell, it took a long time and a bunch of "file or directory not found" error messages started showing up. I was using Lineage Recovery and, following step 5, a clicked on "Reboot system now". Here's a log:

```
C:\Temp>fastboot devices
08460011        fastboot

C:\Temp>fastboot boot recovery.img
Sending 'boot.img' (10884 KB)    OKAY [  0.351s]
Booting                                            OKAY [  0.035s]
Finished. Total time: 0.491s

C:\Temp>adb sideload flo-repart.zip
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Total xfer: 1.00x

C:\Temp>adb shell
flox:/ # modify
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 M) copied, 0.077575 s, 13 M/s
20480+0 records in
20480+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 M) copied, 0.289826 s, 35 M/s
umount: /mnt/system: Invalid argument
umount: /data: Invalid argument
umount: /sdcard: Invalid argument
GNU Parted 1.8.8.1.179-aef3
Using /dev/block/mmcblk0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
                                                      (parted)   rm 22
                                                      (parted)   rm 23
                                                      (parted)   rm 24
                                                      (parted)   rm 25
                                                      (parted)   rm 30
                                                      (parted)   mkpart primary 614429696B 2187293695B
                                                      (parted)   name 22 system
                                                      (parted)   mkpart primary 2187293696B 2263875583B
                                                      (parted)   name 23 cache
                                                      (parted)   mkpart primary 2263875584B 2264924159B
                                                      (parted)   name 24 misc
                                                      (parted)   mkpart primary 2264924160B 2281701375B
                                                      (parted)   name 25 recovery
                                                      (parted)   mkpart primary 2348843008B 2610987007B
                                                      (parted)   name 30 vendor
                                                      (parted)   mkpart primary 2610987008B 15757983231B
                                                      (parted)   name 31 userdata
                                                      (parted)   quit
                                                      Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

mke2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
The file /dev/block/mmcblk0p22 does not exist and no size was specified.
mke2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
The file /dev/block/mmcblk0p23 does not exist and no size was specified.
mke2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
The file /dev/block/mmcblk0p30 does not exist and no size was specified.
mke2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
The file /dev/block/mmcblk0p31 does not exist and no size was specified.
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 M) copied, 0.163787 s, 6.1 M/s
20480+0 records in
20480+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 M) copied, 1.376526 s, 7.2 M/s
```

After rebooting, there is not an operating system in the tablet anymore. All that is possible is to open fastboot mode with VOLUME DOWN + POWER. When USB connected to Windows, it will sound repeatedly as the connection is tried but fails. I tried the next step on the guide, which is to format one of the partitions with "fastboot -w", but it ended in error.

I tried to connect the tablet using fastboot on Ubuntu, but it never did establish a connection. The tablet does not appear with "lsusb", and using "dmesg" I can see the following:

```
[ 3452.967123] usb usb3-port11: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3453.935126] usb usb3-port11: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3453.935202] usb usb3-port11: attempt power cycle
[ 3455.219195] usb usb3-port11: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3456.187128] usb usb3-port11: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3456.187203] usb usb3-port11: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Nevertheless, the tablet is still charging its battery though the USB connection as if the cable and port were working normally.

I hope someone has any insight on this. I really don't understand much of this process, and I hope there's something I'm not doing right that is fixable.

Comment: Making system modifications using an unstable USB connection is a bad idea. First try to fix the USB problem and then start repartitioning and installing the OS.

Comment: flash TWRP recovery + *'adb push flo-deb_clamor_repartition.zip /tmp'* + install zip from TWRP menu (no usb connection needed)